# How can I style the <paper-card> used in my polymer-element

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, styling, paper-elements

Hi I am creating my polymer element in which i am using < paper-card >. I want to change the height & width of my paper-card so that it occupies the entire space. Also i want to make few more changes but I am finding it difficult. I can do it with inline styling like this :

```
<template>
 <div >
 <paper-card heading="OTS Task" animatedShadow="true" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="card-content" >
      <iron-label >Label 1 </iron-label>
      <iron-label> Label 2</iron-label>       
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions">
    <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
    <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
</div>
```

If you see here i have done style="width : 100%" to make it span the entire width. Can anyone tell me how can i write the same in < style > tag.  I read few docs on this but found it very difficult  * New to polymer *. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't think that setting the paper-card element to 100% will work.
I believe that the correct way would be to use mixing as this is the way you [style Polymer elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling).
The correct way in this case would be:

```
  paper-card {
    --paper-card: {
      width: 100%;
    };
  }
```

The alignment of the text would be in this case handled with:

```
  paper-card {
    --paper-card-header-text: {
        text-align: center;
    };
  }
  paper-card {
    --paper-card-content: {
        text-align: center;
    };
  }
```

A full list of the different selectors can be found in the [element description here.](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent CSS for `<paper-card style="width: 100%">` would be:

```
<style>
  paper-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Here's a working demo:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      paper-card {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <div>
        <paper-card heading="OTS Task" animated-shadow="true">
          <div class="card-content" >
            <iron-label >Label 1 </iron-label>
            <iron-label> Label 2</iron-label>       
          </div>
          <div class="card-actions">
            <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
            <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
          </div>
        </paper-card>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OXJQpN/?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks!! If it is this simple then why do we use ::  and also I saw somewhere --> paper-card .heading { -----some css---- } . What does this mean ?

Comment: Also if i have to center align the paper-card heading then how should i proceed. I tried this but did not work -->  paper-card .heading {
        text-align: center;
      }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is="custom-style"` in your style tag and then use paper-card properties as described on elements page or standard CSS properties